# How to logout from two website at the same time- PHP Session handling

Tags: php, session

Suppose we have two websites example.com & example.net in different domains. The user data of both these sites is the same so we can log in to both these sites with the same userid and password.

When a user clicks the logout button on example.com then we also have to log them out from example.net. Both sites are open and logged in on the same browser (on different tabs).

Is it possible to destroy the session cookies of example.net when the user logs out from example.com?

Comment: When you say user data in both sites is the same, does that mean both sites are sharing a database, so you could put a flag in the database?

Comment: Hey phpmeh, It's a good suggestion. But both of these application does not share the same database. Also we do not have the access of database or codebase of 2nd site. Is there any otherway?  Thanx.

Comment: How are you creating a session in both websites at the same time then?  Through an API?

Comment: How can they login with the same credentials, if the 2 sites don't share anything? how does a user who register on one site ends up having the same credentials from the other?

Comment: Hey Damien Pirsy, yes when we are creating an user on site -1, we are calling a web method and that creating the same user on site-2. So with the same credentials user can login to these two different websites.

Comment: if you are calling a 'web method' that can create a user in other site then maybe you can also create a web method that can log out the user at the other side when they log out. just call it every time the user log out.

Answer (score 2):

Since the two sites are not sharing any login information in between, both are keeping independent session data, and you cannot modify the session data of some other website.

A solution is to write an API that communicates to the other website, to destroy the session data.

Example:

**Tab 1** : Opened "Example.**com**" and logged in as "alice"

**Tab 2** : Opened "Example.**net**" and logged in as "alice"

---*Now, to have a "mutual log-out", do the following.*---

When you click "log out" in tab 1 (**.com** domain), it should go to:

- http://example.net/api/remote_logout.php?userid=alice
- AND redirect to:
- http://example.com/logout.php

Similiarly, when you click "log out" in tab 2 (**.net** domain), it should go to:

- http://example.com/api/remote_logout.php?userid=alice
- AND redirect to
- http://example.net/logout.php

I think that is clear for you.

Comment: We had to do the same thing for logging users out of facebook who opted to log into our site using their facebook account.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an intermediary site or webservice that tracks user sessions, i.e. common to both the sites abc.com and xyz.com 
From both the site you can have an ajax request every fix amount of time to check the intermediary service for the validity of user session. If a user logs out in any of the one site the session would destroy. So when the ajax request from other site checks it would get closed session and hence you write in the code to destroy cookies or whatever you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

The following is how I do it in Drupal. If you use any CMS then there will be a specific way to do that, but the core structure is same to support it in the PHP environment. When one site get a login request internally login to the other site with given username and password.

- First login to the site and and get cookie tokes etc. to proceed other stuff relevant to the user's requirements.

Sample code is here for Drupal CMS. You can get the idea how it works and its functionality then copy relevant parts to work in your environment.

```
// Build request data
$user_login_method = 'POST';
$user_login_retry = 0;
$post_data = array('username' => trim($username), 'password' => trim($password));
$user_login_data = http_build_query($post_data, null, '&');

// Send a request with the data to other site
$login_request = drupal_http_request($other_site_login_url, $user_login_headers, $user_login_method, $user_login_data, $user_login_retry);

// Look for set cookie header value in the response
if(isset($login_request->headers['Set-Cookie'])) {
// Set the cookie name and do the rest based on values
}
```

- Second is do call the logout url of other site to logout the user. Keep in mind that you have to used the cookie values returned at the login call but if you make an ajax call from your logout page to the other site then there is no work around.

If you look Drupal site API for more information regarding the [drupal_http_request](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/6) method.

Hope this would help you to do it in your environment with programing skills with PHP.

Answer (score -1):

I would try using session handling storing data in a database.

Comment: Which database? he says the 2 are differents. How does session handling like this work? could you explain? Could you expand this answer, please?

Comment: You could setup a database just for session handling and change PHPs default session handler to use this database. If you do this for both of the domains, it should be possible to store some personal information which is then used to either only have 1 session(ID) or at least to kill both at once when logging out.